# selecting a specific number as column value in the query

Tags: mysql

i think its pretty easy but i couldn't find the answer with searching

i want to do something like this

```
if(!$user_logged)
{
 $q = "select `id` , 0 as choice from tbl1";
}
else
{
 $q = "select tbl1.id , tbl2.choice as choice from tbl1 join tbl2 ON .... ";
}
```

i want to select 0 as the choice if user is not logged so i wouldn't need to do the extra join
but i get

```
Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
```

Comment: `select id , 0 as choice from tbl1` looks like a valid query to me. Are you sure that this produces the error?

Comment: A small change your query needs @max.I have posted the answer.

Comment: @ypercube yes it needed the single quotations

Comment: That's a PHP problem you have. MySQL returns `0` as an integer. If your PHP code expects a string, then this is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query :-

```
SELECT id,'0' AS Choices FROM tbl1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that the error (you show) is produced, is if you have this in your query:

```
select id , `0` as choice from test ;
         ---^ ^------
         ------------ notice the backticks there
```

Make it:

```
select id , 0 as choice from test ;
```

and the query is valid and MySQL will throw no error.

If you want a string returned in PHP (as if `choice` column in a `CHAR()` or `VARCHAR()` column) and you want consistent results from the 2 variations of the query, then use single quotes:

```
select id , '0' as choice from test ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but give this a try :

```
SELECT id AS choice FROM tbl1 WHERE id=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what value you want (0) why do you want to make SQL return it? Just use 0 instead of parsing the value from the query.

Comment: i send the result directly to the template and i dont want to change the template