# how to selecting a specific number as column value in the query In CodIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

referrence question link is this

[selecting a specific number as column value in the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845624/selecting-a-specific-number-as-column-value-in-the-query)

how do I implement same thing in CodeIgniter.

this is my code:

```
$this->db->select(''.$insertId.', itemId, qty, rate');
$this->db->from('tbl_purchaseorderdetail');
$this->db->where('masterId', $purchaseorderId);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
    $this->db->select('"'.$insertId.'" as insertid, itemId, qty, rate');
    $this->db->from('tbl_purchaseorderdetail');
    $this->db->where('masterId', $purchaseorderId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

If you put static value then is it working fine. Check it once so we can go further.

```
    $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
    $this->db->select('34 as insertid, itemId, qty, rate');
    $this->db->from('tbl_purchaseorderdetail');
    $this->db->where('masterId', $purchaseorderId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Insert like this,
Here, $query contains results of your previous query.

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_purchasedetail', $row);
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of $insertId.

Comment: value of $insertId is 34

Comment: codeIgniter is actually putting this sign `` so the database takes it as a column. it should only take 34 rather than `34` in codeIgniter.

Comment: this is the error:

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '34' in 'field list'

SELECT `34` as insertId, `itemId`, `qty`, `rate` FROM (`tbl_purchaseorderdetail`) WHERE `masterId` = '2'

Filename: C:\wamp64\www\applicationName\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: Again i have updated my anser. to remove `` we have to set protect identifiers to false

Comment: after selecting now error is raising at insertion:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 1

INSERT INTO tbl_purchasedetail (`0`, `1`) VALUES (, )

    `$this->db->insert('tbl_purchasedetail', $query->result());`

is this the right way to insert

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it with static value first

Comment: yes that error is gone but how do i insert this result from query into table tbl_purchasedetail

Comment: $this->db->select("'$insertId' as insertid, itemId, qty, rate");

Comment: this statement:
`$this->db->insert('tbl_purchasedetail', $query->result());`

Comment: from your updated answer it is inserting now Thank You So Much :)